# Creating an incidence matrix from data frame with distinct row lengths in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a space separated file, similar to:

```
# 1_1 AAA ABA AAB BBA
# 1_2 ABA AAA ABB BAA
# 1_3 ABA BAA
# 1_4 AAA BBB ABB
```

However, the rows' content (let's call them "words") contains more characters (around 20). The number of words in each row varies (from less than 10 to dozens). I want to create an incidence matrix, using R, where each unique word is a column and the row names would remain as row names, like this:

```
#     AAA AAB ABA ABB BAA BBA BBB
# 1_1  1   1   1   0   0   1   0
# 1_2  1   0   1   1   1   0   0
# 1_3  0   0   1   0   1   0   0
# 1_4  1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

The column order is not relevant. Any advice is very much appreciated, and both base and package solutions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c("1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "1_4"),
      col_1 = c("AAA", "ABA", "ABA", "AAA"),
      col_2 = c("ABA", "AAA", "BAA", "BBB"),
      col_3 = c("AAB", "ABB", NA, "ABB"),
      col_4 = c("BBA", "BAA", NA, NA)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-4L)
  )

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id,
    names_from = value,
    values_from = value,
    values_fn = length,
    values_fill = 0
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#>   id      AAA   ABA   AAB   BBA   ABB   BAA   BBB
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 1_1       1     1     1     1     0     0     0
#> 2 1_2       1     1     0     0     1     1     0
#> 3 1_3       0     1     0     0     0     1     0
#> 4 1_4       1     0     0     0     1     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df)

melt(df, id.vars = "id") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  dcast(formula = id ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
#>     id AAA AAB ABA ABB BAA BBA BBB
#> 1: 1_1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
#> 2: 1_2   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
#> 3: 1_3   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
#> 4: 1_4   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**base**

```r
df_stack <- stack(df, select = -id)
df_stack$id <- rep(df$id, ncol(df) - 1)
+(with(df_stack, table(id, values)))
#>      values
#> id    AAA AAB ABA ABB BAA BBA BBB
#>   1_1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
#>   1_2   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
#>   1_3   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
#>   1_4   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I imported data using the following code:
```n = max(count.fields("file_name.txt"))
data = read.table("file_name.txt", h = F, col.names = c("id", paste("V", seq_len(n))), fill = T)```
I'd prefer using the tidyverse solution, however I got the following error:
Error: Column 35 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
I couldn't figure out how to solve it. The data.table solution worked tho, so I'm sticking with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
> +(t(table(stack(as.data.frame(t(`row.names<-`(df[-1], df$id)))))) > 0)
     values
ind   AAA AAB ABA ABB BAA BBA BBB
  1_1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
  1_2   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
  1_3   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
  1_4   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `unite/cSplit_e`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(splitstackshape)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  unite(new, starts_with('col'), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  cSplit_e(., "new", sep="_", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., "new_"), -id)
   id AAA AAB ABA ABB BAA BBA BBB
1 1_1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
2 1_2   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
3 1_3   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
4 1_4   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```